# SQL Oracle - Decoding entity-attribute-value table with entity repeated

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I have the following table, based on entity-attribute-value system (so for each item, there is a row with an attribute and its value):

```
+----------+-----------+---------+
| EntityID | Attribute | Value   |
+----------+-----------+---------+
| 1        | Name      | Item 1  |
+----------+-----------+---------+
| 1        | Age       | 2       |
+----------+-----------+---------+
| 1        | Cost      | 100     |
+----------+-----------+---------+
| 1        | Cost      | 250     |
+----------+-----------+---------+
| 2        | Name      | Item 2  |
+----------+-----------+---------+
| 2        | Age       | Unknown |
+----------+-----------+---------+
| 2        | Age       | 3       |
+----------+-----------+---------+
| 2        | Cost      | 125     |
+----------+-----------+---------+
```

My objective is to transform the table in a single row with each attribute as a column and it's value in the row with the corresponding entity, like this:

```
+----------+--------+-----+-----------+
| EntityID | Name   | Age | Cost      |
+----------+--------+-----+-----------+
| 1        | Item 1 | 2   | 100 - 250 |
+----------+--------+-----+-----------+
| 2        | Item 2 | 3   | 125       |
+----------+--------+-----+-----------+
```

As you can see, the same attribute may or may not exist multiple times. And depending of the attribute, I may want to concatenate (in this case, concatenate the cost as min and max), or to ignore one of the answers which makes no sense (in this case unknown for age, with maybe a CASE WHEN function).

I'm currently using the DECODE function which changes the attributes into columns and takes max:

```
SELECT  ENTITYID
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE, 'Name', VALUE)) AS "Name"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE, 'Age', VALUE)) AS "Age"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE, 'Cost', VALUE)) AS "Cost"
FROM    DECODING
GROUP BY ENTITYID;
```

Obviously, it does not work once it must choose between values, since it takes max. How can I treat those cases knowing that my table contains 50+ attributes ? Here is the result.

```
+----------+--------+---------+------+
| EntityID | Name   | Age     | Cost |
+----------+--------+---------+------+
| 1        | Item 1 | 2       | 250  |
+----------+--------+---------+------+
| 2        | Item 2 | Unknown | 125  |
+----------+--------+---------+------+
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a bit more logic to handle your different cases:

```
SELECT ENTITYID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE = 'Name' THEN VALUE END) AS Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE = 'Age' AND VALUE <> 'UNKNOWN' THEN VALUE END) AS Age,
       (MIN(CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE = 'Cost' THEN Value END) ||
        (CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE = 'Cost' THEN Value END) > 1
              THEN '-' || MAX(CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE = 'Cost' THEN Value END)
         END)
        ) as Cost
FROM DECODING
GROUP BY ENTITYID;
```

I recommend using `CASE` expressions instead of `DECODE()`.  `CASE` is ANSI-standard syntax and a bit more flexible.

Comment: I tried your query and there is an error (missing right paranthesis). I tried fixing it, but I can't seem to fix it. It is in `COUNT(DISTINCT ATTRIUTE = 'Cost')`.

Comment: I will try to use more ``CASE`` expressions, thanks for the tip.